# Angular 6-cli with Webpack 4

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm trying to set up a simple angular 6 project with webpack 4 and I'm looking for a simple guide on how to set up a webpack config with all the new changes between angular v6 and webpack v4. Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10618

Answer (score 0):

if without the CLI, currently ng eject is disabled so you cannot customize the webpack config from v6 cli.

But if no cli,

https://blog.angularindepth.com/upgrading-a-project-without-cli-to-angular-6-b07b105adc02